# Elegant alternative to df[df.columns[0]]

Tags: python, pandas

If I want to call the first column of a df without knowing the name of the df, I usually use `df[df.columns[0]]`. When I use boolean indexing it looks for example like this:

```
df[df[df.columns[0] > value].count()
```

Is there a more elegant way to write this? This nesting appears to be very error-prone.

Comment: there's some typo in your code on parentheses: three opened, two closed @PDistl

Comment: Why using count? `df.iloc[:,0].gt(value).sum()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to index dataframe based on integer position.

```py
df.iloc[:, 0].gt(value).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# importing pandas package
import pandas as pd
  
# making data frame from csv file
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ....])
 
  
df[[True, False, True, False, True, False ...]]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).